# What is the jitter effect on the spectrum of impulse train?

Tags: power-spectral-density, random-process

How to derive the sepctrum of $$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(t-nT-\tau_n\right)$$
where $\tau_n\sim N\left(0, \sigma^2\right)$

I assume that the randomness effect should behave as a low pass. Yet, I am struggling to derive it analytically.

Comment: We call that "***jitter***".  Since it makes your impulse train non-periodic, then there is no Fourier Series, but there can be an autocorrelation and a power spectrum, since this is now a random process.

Comment: Even worse, the process that you have constructed is not WSS, and so the autocorrelation function is a function of two variables, and the power spectrum is more complicated than just the Fourier transform of a univariate autocorrelation function of a WSS process.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What do you think of the direction below?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, assuming the mean period, $T_0$, is fixed what are the two variables?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson $R_{xx}(t_1,t_2) = E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ is _in general_ a function of the two time instants $t_1$, and $t_2$. Note $R_{xx}(t_1,t_2)=R_{xx}(t_2,t_1)$. Think of the function as defining a surface above a plane with coordinate axes $t_1$ and $t_2$. The surface has a ridge along the line $t_1=t_2$. For a WSS process, the function has constant value along the straight line $t_1-t_2=\alpha$, and so the autocorrelation function can be expressed as a function of just one variable $\alpha$; for all $t_1, t_2$ such that $t_1-t_2=\alpha$, $R_{xx}(t_1,t_2)$ has value $R_x(\alpha)$.

Comment: So @DilipSarwate , how is this ***not*** WSS?  How are the statistics any different for one $t_1$ and $t_2$ vs. a different $t_1$ and $t_2$ as long as their difference (their spacing) remains the same $t_1-t_2$?

Answer (score 1):

For $$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(t-nT-\tau_n\right)$$
where $\tau_n\sim N\left(0, \sigma^2\right)$

The expected value is given by
$$E\left[x(t)\right]=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t-nT}{\sigma}\right)^2}$$
This can be represented as a convolution
$$E\left[x(t)\right]=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}*\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(t-nT\right)$$

Or
$$E\left[x(t)\right]=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}*\text{Ш}_{T}\left(t\right)$$
Considering the convolution theorem, and using the known identity for the normal distribution characteristic function, the spectrum can be represented as

$$E\left[x(f)\right]=e^{-\frac{f^2\sigma^2}{2}}\text{Ш}_{T}\left(f\right)$$

The characteristic function of the normal distribution behaves as a low-pass filter (decaying exponential). This is what I wanted to derive.